# Trying to run eBPF BCC Tools offcputime fails with error

Tags: kernel

```
$ /usr/share/bcc/tools/offcputime
```

The above command says it can't find this directory: `/lib/modules/4.9.0-040900rc2-generic/kernel/build`.

I think it has something to do with not having the linux-tools for this kernel.

Can't install linux tools for latest kernel.

```
 E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-4.9.0-040900rc2-generic
```

Or maybe I installed it wrong with dpkg...  Got the .deb files here:  http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9-rc2/

Answer (score 1):

BCC needs the kernel headers to compile its eBPF programs. So you'll also need to download and install the `.deb` files for kernel headers.

(I was able to reproduce your bug and fix by installing the 2 `.deb` files from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.9-rc2/ for kernel headers.)